# Setting position of custom SKSpriteNode from GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am making a custom SKSpriteNode, when I step through calling createShip the heroShip constant in the class is correct, but when I jump back to the gameScene, the heroShip constant there does not have the properties I assigned when calling createShip, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried using class function but that doesn't work using the height and width properties.

Custom SKSpriteNode class

```
class hero: SKSpriteNode {
    var width: CGFloat = 0.0
    var height: CGFloat = 0.0

     func createShip() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let heroShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heroShip")
            heroShip.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
            heroShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: heroShip.size)
            heroShip.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
              heroShip.zPosition = 1.0
            heroShip.physicsBody?.mass = 0.02
            heroShip.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            heroShip.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            heroShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue
            heroShip.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue
            heroShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0 | ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue

            //heroShip.position = CGPointMake((scene?.frame.size.width)!/6.0, (scene?.frame.size.height)!/2.0)

        heroShip.position = CGPointMake(width, height)

        return heroShip


    }
}
```

My GameScene

```
class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate{


    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    var score:Int = 0
    let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Courier")
    let MotionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var heroShip = hero()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        heroShip.width = self.size.width/6.0
        heroShip.height = self.size.height/2.0
        heroShip.createShip()
        let enemyShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(0,heroShip.size.width/1.25,frame.width,frame.height - heroShip.size.width*1.6))
        scene?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue
        scene?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        scoreLabel.text = String(format: "Score: %01u",score)
        scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height - scoreLabel.frame.size.width/1.2)
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 1.0


        enemyShip.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        enemyShip.zPosition = 1.0
        enemyShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: heroShip.size)
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.mass = 0.02
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue
        enemyShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0

        self.addChild(enemyShip)
        self.addChild(background)
        self.addChild(self.heroShip)
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)

        if MotionManager.accelerometerAvailable{
            MotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(heroShip.position.x, heroShip.position.y)
        bullet.zPosition = 1.0
        // Add physics body for collision detection
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.frame.size)
        bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
        let action = SKAction.moveToX(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + bullet.size.width, duration: 0.75)
        self.addChild(bullet)
        bullet.runAction(action, completion: {
            bullet.removeAllActions()
            bullet.removeFromParent()
        })
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory.collisionBulletCategory.rawValue && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ObjectCategory.collisionEnemyCategory.rawValue{
        score++
        }
    }



    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        let data = MotionManager.accelerometerData
        if data?.acceleration.x == nil{
            print("nil")
        }
        else if fabs((data?.acceleration.x)!) > 0.2 {
            heroShip.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(0.0, CGFloat(40 * (data?.acceleration.x)!)))
        }

        scoreLabel.text = String(format: "Score: %01u",score)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run

```
heroShip.createShip()
```

and then never do anything with the `SKSpriteNode` that is returned.  From what I can tell, the hero class *is* the hero ship.  I am going off of this assumption for the rest of this answer.

Going from the top of the `GameScene`, you should do some refactoring.

`var heroShip = hero()` Is going to be replaced to init using the `SKSpriteNode` structure:

```
var heroShip = hero(imageNamed: "heroShip")
```

Moving to `hero` class, `func createShip() -> SKSpriteNode {` should be turned into `func createShip() {`.  As you already have the node set up with the image texture now, and are using the `hero` class as the node, there is no need to return a `SKSpriteNode`.

Delete `let heroShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heroShip")` as the `hero` class *is* going to be our `heroShip`.

Replace any usage of the `heroShip.whatever` variable with `self.whatever`.  At the end, delete the `return heroShip`.

Comment: Why make it a 2 step process?  Just rewrite the convenience init to handle the `SKPhysicsBody`,  That is 1 less step to have to worry about when creating a new hero

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I wasn't sure what the OP's plan was with that, so I didn't touch it.

Comment: I will have to verify that when I get home,  I do not believe you would have to implement it, since you are using the base class's designated constructor, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Gliderman so how would you handle making the position dynamic so that it is scaled for all screen sizes? Thats been my main problem is how to get the 'GameScene.size' into the createShip

Comment: Just get the parent node's size of your hero

Comment: and you don't implement the createShip using this to set the physics and the position etc

Comment: how would you do that from the hero class though @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101134/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-brandon-tomblinson).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not be understanding what is happening with your code.

As of right now `createShip()` is creating a hero ship, but you never use it.

By looking at your code, it seems like `createShip()` is not even needed. From looking at it, hero IS heroShip, so do the code in your init.

```
    convenience init(imageNamed: String,sceneSize:CGSize) {
    let heroTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)

    self.init(texture: heroTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: heroTexture.size()) //This may need to be tweeked, my mac is dead right now to verify.
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.zPosition = 1.0
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 0.02
    self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    heroShip.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategory.collisionHeroCategory.rawValue
        heroShip.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue
        heroShip.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0 | ObjectCategory.sceneCategory.rawValue

    //self.position = CGPointMake((scene?.frame.size.width)!/6.0, (scene?.frame.size.height)!/2.0)

    self.position = CGPointMake(sceneSize.width, sceneSize.height)



}
```

You now come across another problem,  and that is your `SKPhysicsBody` will not align to your anchor point.

To fix this, create the `SKPhysicsBody` like this:

```
let centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2 - (self.size.width * self.anchorPoint.x), self.size.height / 2 - (self.size.height * self.anchorPoint.y))
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size, center: centerPoint)
```

Comment: I fixed this,  color also needed to be added since that is the one with the delegating constructor,  plus I added sceneSize since we talked about you needing it in the chat,  so to create a hero, do let heroShip = hero(imageNamed:"heroShip",sceneSize:self.size)

Comment: you have other issues as well, your other issues are bodyA is never guaranteed to be bullet, so you need to account for both cases where bodyA is bullet and bodyB is bullet,  and your categories need to be in a power of 2,  these are bit mask flags, so 3 actually means sceneCategory and collissionHero, because in binary, 3 is 0011 (Thus 2 categories),  but you need to make it 0100 in binary to give it a unique category